# Show and Hide Navigation and Tab Bar in Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing a iOS application having tabBar navigation. My requirement is that first time the app starts I need to play a video which should show on top of the tabbar and the navigation bar. To do this I did -

```
self.tabBarController!.tabBar.hidden = true
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.hidden = true
```

But if I hide the tabBar and navigation Bar, the elements in my View which shows after the video is played get stretched. Can some one give me a better solution to this. XCode 8.0, Swift 2.3

Thanks.

Comment: "get stretched" is not enough information to help anyone understand the problem. You'll need to post some actual code and/or screenshots of the issue if you want help. See [mcve]

Comment: By "get stretched" I mean the position of the elements in the View changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set,

```
 self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=true;
```

You can set it from `interface builder` also - `select your view controller - attribute inspector - under view controller - Check Under opaque bars(under extend edges)`

Comment: This had no effect unfortunately.